# How to copy a RecordSet contents on a split Range in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, recordset

I have one ADODB.RecordSet with 1 row and 4 columns.
I want to copy the content of the recordset in the range "A1:B1, D1:E1", skipping "C1".
The range was creat with the Union function.
(yes, I know I could simply copy it field-by-field but I'm using that range later and I also prefer to reduce the number or writing events to the minimum)

Note: I'm extremely new at VBA and Excel. Like: 3 weeks new.
Would have gladily skipped them, but job demands them.

What I tried:

```
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim QueryResults As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString as String
    Dim QuerySql as String

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set QueryResults = New ADODB.Recordset
    sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=DB_IP_ADDRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_CATALOG;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=DB_USER_ID;Password=DB_USER_PASSWORD;"
    QuerySql="Select field_1,field_2,field_3,field_4 from table"

    conn.Open sConnString
    Set QueryResults = conn.Execute(QuerySql)

    Dim Unione As Range
    Set Unione = Union( _
        Sheets(FoglioMonda).Range("A1", "B1") , _
        Sheets(FoglioMonda).Range("D1", "E1") )
    
    Unione.CopyFromRecordset QueryResults

    conn.close
```

What I expected:
Excel copying the content of the RecordSet in the range I gave it, thus skippign "C1" and copying the contents of field_3 and field_4 in "D1" and "E1" respectively

What I got:
Excel not skipping "C1"

Comment: You can't do that with `Copyfromrecordset`. You could use two `GetRows` calls and restrict the fields for each one (the arrays will be transposed from what you need so you'll need to transpose them back and remember to use MoveFirst between the two calls). Might be easier to just dump all the data somewhere else temporarily and then copy and paste it to your two ranges.

Comment: If C1 is blank then `Select field_1,field_2,NULL,field_3,field_4 from table`